# Rails MySQL master/slave send both reads and writes to master

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, replication

Most of the rails plugins I found for a rails master slave setup seem to want to send all writes to the master and all reads to the slave.

This seems like a loss of resources to me. Is there a way to send reads to both master and slave, and writes only to the slave?

If this is a bad idea, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what Master-Slave means.

A slave does not give the master orders as to what data it can take in.

If a master gives information to a slave, the slave can pass it on without bothering the master. The master can then concentrate on the job of acquiring information.

So, when you have a master-slave database, the master acquires data and passes it on to the slave(s) who can then pass it on to those requesting it.